# Can I build SaaS based e commerce platform using Magento?

Tags: cloud, saas

I am thinking of building a SaaS based e commerce model like Shopify.in. So, that I can sell e commerce at lower rates to the audience in local region with template based design approach.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes it's possible but the technical 'how' would be way too broad to go into in an answer. First of all you'll need to think about how to scale the application over several servers. And if you want to put all clients on a shared installation or some other way

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the specifics of the license agreements, but I believe that the Community Edition license would allow this. Enterprise Edition specifically does not.

Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer; you should consult an expert in licensing before launching your venture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will not be cheap or fast.

You sure need a year of development work to be able to compete, and maybe another year to establish in the market.

I would say, dont even try it, but thats independent of magento, as you would need a software which is specialized on this topic, which is not true for magento and also not for most other eCommerce platforms.